# Как в hibernate будет выглядеть запрос

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, requests

Начинаю изучать hibernate с обычными фильтрациями я разорался(find(параметр(ы),findBy...(параметр(ы))), но как составить запрос следующего вида? Спасибо!

```
SELECT * FROM public.images
WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM public.images)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ты можешь использовать аннотацию Query от spring в твоем случае код будет такой:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;

@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM public.images
WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM public.images)", nativeQuery = true)
```

Я делал это следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]